# How to change the response code of startActivityForResult in child activity

Tags: java, android

I am opening a second activity using startActivityForResult, I am sending a request code from the main activity that is received by onActivityResult.

but **I want to know if it is possible to change that request code in the secondary activity** so that I don't have to receive the same code in the main activity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/8956604. request code and result code are different things.

Comment: Why would you want to? You are attempting to change the purpose of the request code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be receiving a result code not a request code in your SecondActivity. The last example code in this [source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java) may be consistent with what you are trying to do. If this isn't what you are looking for, try posting your code to give us more context.